# The ABAP program lines are wider than the internal table

Tags: sap, abap

seré breve.

Resulta que tengo un programa al cual le he hecho unas modificaciones las  cuales funcionan correctamente, el problema es cuando cierro el ERP e intento ingresar nuevamente para ejecutar el programa, me aparece el error que describí en el titulo, pero cuando dejo el código que estaba antes de mis modificaciones vuelve a funcionar normal, como estaba.

Analisis del error:

```
An exception occurred that is explained in detail below.
The exception, which is assigned to class 'CX_SY_READ_SRC_LINE_TOO_LONG', was
 not caught in
procedure "K_KKB_FIELDCAT_MERGE" "(FUNCTION)", nor was it propagated by a
 RAISING clause.
Since the caller of the procedure could not have anticipated that the
exception would occur, the current program is terminated.
The reason for the exception is:
There was an attempt to read program "ZSD_REPORTE_DIARIO_FACT2" from the
 database.
The READ REPORT statement allows you to copy a program text into an
internal table. The occupied line length in the program text must not
exceed the width of the internal table.
The internal table "\FUNCTION=K_KKB_FIELDCAT_MERGE\DATA=L_ABAP_SOURCE[]" is 72
 characters wide. The program line is
95 characters wide.
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, y que quede para la posteridad:

- Ingresar a la transacción SE38(Editor ABAP)
- Digitar el reporte que este presentando el inconveniente de longitud de lineas
- Clic en modificar
     Una vez en el código hacer lo siguiente (Espero tenga el SAP Logon en español)
         -Se ubican en la parte de arriba y buscan:
              Utilidades --> Mas utilidades --> Forzar longitud de lineas

Activan, y ya esta. A mi me funciono de esa manera.

Answer (score 2):

El programa lo migraste de un cliente a otro? a mi paso ese problema con un programa del ECC a S4, el problema era el tamaño de las lineas de código del programa, no marcaba error al compilar solo era al ejecutar.

Espero sea este el problema.

Saludos

Comment: Según comentarios en foros de SAP, este es muy posiblemente el problema [(enlace)](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5061060/oss-note-for-read-report-cxsyreadsrclinetoolong.html)